# How can I disable the "dimming" of the code completion popup in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The code completion popup which comes up automatically in IntelliJ IDEA looks like this:

> [image: Popup dimmed]

As you can see, It's dimmed, or "faded" and hard to read. (Screenshot is fine, but the real one is hard to read.)

After I click on it, it looks like this:

> [image: Not dimmed]

As you can see it's no longer dimmed or faded, but I *always* have to click on it to un-dim it.

**How can I make it always fully visible and not dimmed ?**

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the autocomplete popup fully visible is to select *Settings/Editor/General/Code Completion/Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc*.

This is however not just an appearance setting, so it also changes the way autocomplete behaves, which may or may not be good depending on your preference.

I am not aware of any option which would purely disable the dimming. You could try posting a feature request for that on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com.

Comment: Yep, I don't really want to change the way autocomplete works. Thanks anyway.